# TypeError: object of type 'numpy.int64' has no len() / TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()/ while using classification_report in scikitlearn

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, metrics

Sometimes when using sklearn.metrics.classification_report we get below error

```
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Sometime depending on the datatype we get error like below too

```
TypeError: object of type 'numpy.int64' has no len()
```

Sample code when we might get this error

```
t=pd.Series([1,2,3,4])
p=np.asarray([1,2,3,4])
target_names=[1,2,3,4]
print(classification_report(t, p, target_names=target_names))
```

Answer (score 4):

This happens when `target_names` used are not string; to solve did a conversion like below on the `target_names` variable

```
t=pd.Series([1,2,3,4])
p=np.asarray([1,2,3,4])
target_names=[1,2,3,4]
target_names=list(map(str,target_names))
print(classification_report(t, p, target_names=target_names))
```

Comment: Same solution for using `metric.load('bertscore')` in `HuggingFace`